# FindHamiltonianPath progress

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm using `FindHamiltonianPath` on a large graph (372 vertices).  Finding a Hamiltonian path of similar graph with 371 vertices took several minutes. But script for 372 vertices is running already several days.  Why might the task take so much longer than for a graph with just one fewer vertex?  Is it possible to see some progress or at least to know if script is really working on my task?

Comment: I would say that this would also critically depend on the number of edges. Can you show how you generated the graphs so? That would make it way easier to tell...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Here it is the graph integerQ[x_] := x == Round[x]; Graph[Select[
  Table[Table[{i <-> j}, {i, 1, j - 1}], {j, 1, 372}] // Flatten, 
  integerQ[Sqrt[#[[1]] + #[[2]]]] &]]

Comment: Any development on this? I am having the same issue. The graph I am using has every vertex numbered 1 to 372 and edges only connect vertices that sum to a square. Is that the nature of your graph as well?